# How to open choose application dialog in cocoa swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I wanted to open a choose application dialog like in mac, dialog open when i choose open With option for any file and tap other, a dialog appear to choose application for opening the file.

[image]

Can i open choose application dialog like in mac for any file type via code in swift/objective c.

I have tried implementing same functionality via NSOpenPanel but look like that is not for choosing application for file. I need exact functionality like in mac with Enable option.

Comment: `NSOpenPanel` is a subclass of `NSSavePanel` which allows you to add [accessory view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/1525544-accessoryview?language=objc): _You can customize the panel by adding a custom view. The custom object you add appears just above the OK and Cancel buttons at the bottom of the panel._

Comment: That _is_ an NSOpenPanel, the Finder just does some work to initially enable selections to applications that have declared to the system that they can open the selected file, with an accessory view to enable all applications.

Comment: While you can't use Finder _applications selection_, you can add your custom logic and mimick the behavior with accessory view and [`optional func panel(_ sender: Any, 
       shouldEnable url: URL) -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopensavepaneldelegate/1535200-panel). But I have a hard time to understand what OP wants exactly.